# Redirecting external ports to local ip

Tags: networking, server, ftp, iptables

I have a ubuntu 13.10 server and a registered domain name. I have a web server on my 192.168.24.1 machine and a ftp server on my 192.168.24.2.

Using iptables I want:

1) people who write : http://mydomainname.com to be redirected to 192.168.24.1

2) people who want to use my ftp (filezilla or something inputing mydomainname)to be redirected to 192.168.24.2

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: You would want a DNS service somewhere on your server or a DNS between your server and external network.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can not give exact answer because I don't know your topology

Case 1.

```
__________________
|                |
|   PC           |-------|
|  192.168.24.1  |       |     _____________
------------------       |_____|           |  __________
                         |     | ip_tables |  |        |
                         |     | PC        |--| router |--- internet
__________________       |     |           |  |        |
|                |       |     -------------  ----------
|   PC           |-------|
| 192.168.24.2   |
------------------
```

In this topology you need iptables

Case 2.

```
__________________
|                |
|   PC           |-------|
|  192.168.24.1  |       |
------------------       |  __________
                         |  |        |
                         |--| router |
__________________       |  |        |
|                |       |  ----------
|   PC           |-------|
| 192.168.24.2   |
------------------
```

You don't need iptables. You need to do port forwarding on router.

- port 80 is for http -> 24.1
- port 443 is for https -> 24.1
- port 20 is FTP data transfer -> 24.2
- port 21 FTP control -> 24.2

Also you must have fix public ip address on wan interface of your router.
Then you must make dns record. DNS resolv logical name aka mydomainname.com to ip address and ip address to logical names.

192.168.x.x range is private range of ip address I can't be router via internet.

Traffic flow is:

- I type mydomainname.com in browser on my pc
- PC ask DNS to resolve mydomainname.com to ip
- When pc have ip, send http/https request to given ip
- web server answer and send traffic to requester

IP address plan:

`PC [private ip}` -> `router with private address on LAN and public ip on WAN. Router do NAT` -> `internet [only public ip address`

Edit 2

Fallowing will work if your server do nat for 24.2 via 24.1

The first thing to do is do enable IP forwarding. This is done either by using

```
 echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
```

or

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

Then, we will add a rule telling to forward the traffic on port 21 to ip 192.168.24.2 on port 21

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 21 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.24.2:21
```

Then, we will add a rule telling to forward the traffic on port 20 to ip 192.168.24.2 on port 20

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 20 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.24.2:20
```

and finally, we ask IPtables to masquerade

```
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

Comment: My totpology: Internet --> Ubuntu 13.10 server(192.168.24.1) --> Switch --> ftp server (192.168.24.2)

Comment: I just want the actual iptables rules to put in 192.168.24.1 to forward port 80 to localhost and ports 21, 22 to 192.168.24.2

Comment: Ubuntu server have two nic cards? One for internet up link, one for  lan? In this setup you don't need to rdr traffic to localhost if is 42.1 on nic from sever.

Comment: Yes, it has 2 nics. I want the iptables rules to redirect 21, 22 to 24.2

Comment: Because your traffic for 24.2 go via 24.1 do you do NAT on 24.1?

Comment: That`s what i want to do, but i can`t figure out the iptables command

Comment: You have code in edit 2 section of answer